# Windows Service Database Update

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-3.5, windows-services

I have a windows service that polls an Oracle database at a given interval and, based on some criteria, updates several fields.  To do this it opens a cursor and iterates through the rows to update.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{      
    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(DoStuff);
    serviceTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 0, 20000);
}

private void DoStuff(object state)
{
    // Set-up connectionsString and sqlQuery

    using (OracleConnection oraConnect = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        oraConnect.Open();

        using (OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, oraConnect))
        using (OracleDataReader oraReader = oraCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (oraReader.Read())
            {
                  // Do some processing here – may take some time

                  // Update database here
            }
        }
}
```

My question is, say for example the timer interval is 20 seconds (as above).  What happens if the cursor takes 30 seconds to iterate through?  I realise that each timer will work in a separate thread, but given that a new database connection is established each time, will the second call see the changes made by the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second process will only see changes committed by the first. If the second process starts before the first commits, then it will not see the changes made by the first.

The assumption made is that one commit is performed in your process. If you are performing a commit after each update, then all bets are off. Your second process will see some of the updates performed by the first, but not all - only those committed when the cursor is opened in the second process.

Answer (score 0):

If you scare that the cursor takes more than 20seconds, you can stop your timer before processes, and then re-start timer after process completed. Is it possible for you to stop timer before process?

Comment: I suppose so, but my question was more: "What will happen?" rather than "How can I get around it?"

Comment: aha sorry I miss understand :)